# Angular Reactive Form : How to call services dynamically for a single form component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

Okay i have created a single reactive form component.
For example say the form is an address form.

The data model for given reactive address form is

```
export interface Address {
addressId: number;
addressTypeValueId: number;
addressLine1: string;
addressLine2: string;
addressLine3: string;
postalId: number;
cityId: number;
stateCode: string;
countryCode: string;
primaryInd: string;
createDatetime: Date;
updateDatetime: Date;
createUserId: number;
updateUserId: number;
```

}

And the Reactive form i have created is

```
addressForm = new FormGroup ({
    name: new FormControl()
});
```

Now i want to call the **addressForm** on different components. 
For example i have three different component Say School, College, Hospital

All of these three components have 3 different data models along with three different services. **postSchool** **postCollege** **postHospital**

I'll be adding the {form_component} in these three different components and then submitting the data into the respective model.

Now i don't know how to bind a service dynamically with **Submit** button so when i call submit on the form. It should call the appropriate service depending inside which component it has been called.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your issue. But since you are adding the form the specific components, the different components will obviously know what service to use. And you should maybe consider delegating the actual submitting the those components instead of the generic form component

Answer (score 1):

If these three components are together in a parent component, you can have `addressForm` in the parent component and receive as an [`@input`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) in each of these three components. If not and if possible, try to wrap them in a parent component.

You could also have a service/provider that contains the formGroup and those three components can import this service on their constructors, gaining access to the same formGroup inside the service

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest handling submit click in the component itself.

You can use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in your `addressForm`, and capture the same in your component.